# Isolate singletons in groups using Stienen sets and dilation

Tags: r, spatstat

I would like to form groups of points using Steiner sets (`spatstat::dilation`).

There are singletons which need to be removed, and I am thinking of using Stienen sets (`spatstat::stienenSet`) for that: for singletons Stienen > Steiner.

How can this be done?

```
library(spatstat)

a=stienenSet(redwood)
b=dilation(redwood, r=0.03)

plot(a, col='orange', main="")
plot(b,add=T, main="")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `connected.ppp` to find connected compnents and identify
singletons that way (sorry for the quick uncommented code):

```r
library(spatstat)
## Points within distance R are connected.
## This should happen when two discs of radius r=0.03 touch each other,
## i.e., R=r+r=0.06:
cc <- connected(redwood, R=0.06)
s <- split(cc)
np <- sapply(s, npoints)
X <- s[np==1]
X <- unmark(superimpose(X))
Y <- s[np>1]
Y <- unmark(superimpose(Y))
plot(dilation(X, 0.03), main = "", col = "orange")
plot(dilation(Y, 0.03), add = TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the nifty solution! The only required comment would be in the `connected(redwood, R=0.06)` line - you have to go from radius to diameter here I suppose. I did not know about the `R` argument.

Comment: Yes! Thanks and sorry for the late reaction. I can't find the R argument in the `connected` function...but this is clear.

Comment: This is because `connected` is generic. Since the first argument in this case is a `ppp` it dispatches to `connected.ppp` where you can find `R` in the help file.

Comment: ah! thanks. I discovered that my question in the `R=r+r` part in your answer is related to a diameter / radius mixup in my understanding and the difference in definitions in ?nndist (nndist/2) and ?stienen (nndist).